# Separate user logins all behave as one user?

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 6 and currently users can login and submit a Group which get's stored in the database.

I've just noticed that if I create a fresh Group for, say user#1 .. and then logout and register as user#2, I see the same Group for both users.

Somehow the Groups CRUD has globalized to all users?

I've tried to go through the code but can't see where this has gone wrong. It was all working last week!

GroupController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Group;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// All Groups pages require login except 'show'
class GroupsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'show']);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $groups = Group::all();

        return view('groups/index', compact('groups'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('groups.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)

    {
        $request->validate([
            'group_title' => 'required',
            'group_description' => 'required',
            'group_date' => 'required',
            'group_time' => 'required',
        ]);

        $group = new Group([
            'group_title' => $request->get('group_title'),
            'group_description' => $request->get('group_description'),
            'group_date' => $request->get('group_date'),
            'group_time' => $request->get('group_time'),
        ]);
        $group->save();
        return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group saved!!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $group = Group::find($id);
        return view('groups.show', compact('group'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $group = Group::find($id);
        return view('groups.edit', compact('group'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'group_title' => 'required',
            'group_description' => 'required',
            'group_date' => 'required',
            'group_time' => 'required',
        ]);

        $group = Group::find($id);
        $group->group_title =  $request->get('group_title');
        $group->group_description = $request->get('group_description');
        $group->group_date = $request->get('group_date');
        $group->group_time = $request->get('group_time');
        $group->save();
        return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group updated!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $group = Group::find($id);
        $group->delete();

        return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group deleted!');
    }
}
```

Groups index page

````
 <tbody>
                                    @foreach($groups as $group)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$group->created_at->format('d M, Y')}}</td>

                                        <td><a href="{{ route('groups.show',$group->id)}}">{{$group->group_title}}</a></td>

                                        <td><a href="">Members</a></td>

                                        <td><a href="">Image link</a></td>

                                        <td>
                                            <a href="{{ route('groups.edit', $group->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Edit</a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <form action="{{ route('groups.destroy', $group->id)}}" method="post">
                                                @csrf
                                                @method('DELETE')
                                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                                                <!-- fas fa-trash fa-fw text-danger -->
                                            </form>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>```
````

Comment: Is the markup you posted `groups/index.blade.php`? In that case, your method index method in `GroupController` returns `Group::all();` without filtering on users or anything else. Correct me if I'm looking at the wrong part of the code.

Comment: That's correct, I have a folder called ```groups``` with four pages inside it for dealing with the groups: ```index.blade.php``` ```create.blade.php``` ```edit.blade.php``` ```show.blade.php```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the groups that belongs to the authenticated user

```php
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $groups = auth()->user()->groups;

    return view('groups.index', compact('groups'));
}
```

Provided a relationship setup in your `app/User.php` model

```php
public function groups()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Group');
}
```

And a migration for groups table like this

```php
Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('group_title');
    $table->text('group_description');
    $table->date('group_date');
    $table->time('group_time');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Given you specify which user created the group

```php
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'group_title' => 'required',
        'group_description' => 'required',
        'group_date' => 'required',
        'group_time' => 'required',
    ]);

    $group_created = Group::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'group_title' => $request->get('group_title'),
        'group_description' => $request->get('group_description'),
        'group_date' => $request->get('group_date'),
        'group_time' => $request->get('group_time'),
    ]);
    if ($group_created) {
        return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group saved!!');
    }
    return redirect('/groups')->with('failed', 'Could not create group');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When doing the migration, do I simply add the code provided by you and run ```php artisan migrate``` or should I make a brand new migration to send to database? Not sure on how that's done/